# I am trying to print the sum of all numbers up to an input "n"

Tags: python

```
#This program defines a function named find_sum to calculate the sum of numbers
#from 0 to n, where n is number entered by a user

#input = 3 so 1 + 2 + 3 = 6(result)
#input = 10 result = 55

n = int(input("Enter a number: "))

def main(): 
    
    result = find_sum(n)
    print("The result is", result)
    
        
def find_sum (n):

    sum = 0
    while ( n >= 0):
        sum += n
        n -= 1
        return sum
        
main()
```

The problem is that it would print the value n without computing the sum. I am not sure how to fix it. I also want to know if there's a way to do this recursively.

Comment: How many times will your loop run before returning a value?

Comment: And, BTW, a better way to do this is `return n * (n + 1) // 2`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm not trying to optimize the code rn, but the while loop seems to only run once because if n = 3, then then result is 3 etc

Comment: Right.  Because your `return` statement is inside the loop.  It will return during the first iteration, and never run any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a number of problems with your code. But the main issue is that you `return sum` inside the loop, you should reduce the indent:

```
def find_sum(n):
    sum = 0
    while (n >= 0):
        sum += n
        n -= 1
    return sum
```

Some other remarks:

- you shouldn't use names like `sum` since they "shadow" a built-in name. `sum()` is a built-in function for summing values.
- you define a `main()` function, which is good, but then proceed to perform part of the logic one would expect in the main body outside the function (the input and type conversion).
- you call a function from `main()` that hasn't been defined at that point; not impossible, but generally it's good form to define something before you use it.
- you use a `while` loop, where a more succinct `for` loop would work better.

With that in mind:

```
def find_sum(n):
    total = 0
    for x in range(n):
        total += x + 1
    return total


def main():
    n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    result = find_sum(n)
    print("The result is", result)


main()
```

A more succinct way of writing `find_sum()`:

```
def find_sum(n):
    return sum(range(n + 1))
```

Finally, the point of defining a `main()` function in Python is often to make your script reusable as a module you can then `import` without running the main logic.

However, to avoid that from happening you need to run the `main()` conditional upon the script being the main script (or just a module):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So, the result:

```
def find_sum(n):
    return sum(range(n + 1))


def main():
    n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    result = find_sum(n)
    print("The result is", result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, as use @timroberts pointed out in the comments, for this particular problem, the outcome is the same as `n * (n + 1) // 2`, so there's no  real need to loop - but that's optimising beyond what has been asked of you, perhaps.

Comment: Appreciate this, it literally solved the problem

Comment: You're welcome, if you think this answers your question, consider clicking the checkmark next to the answer, so that your question no longer appears as 'unanswered'